# How to change background color on Item in actionBar after it is pressed and keep the background?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, drawable, android-styles

I would like to to change background color on Item in actionBar after it is pressed and keep the background.
Now I get to change the background color when I press the item on ActionBar but it when I release the item the background color came back as before.

Keep the color as in the image after I release the item:

[image]

menu.xml

```
  <item android:id="@+id/object_classification" android:orderInCategory="95" android:title="@string/title" android:actionLayout="@style/AppTheme" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
 </style>
```

ab_item_background.xml (in drawable)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
  <!-- focused/pressed: color=holo_orange_light -->
  <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
  <!-- pressed: color=holo_green_light -->
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
  <!-- normal: color=transparent -->
  <item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Thanks a lot